# Launch safari from ios webapp link

Tags: javascript, ios, iframe, safari

I am trying to include some instagram photos in my ios webapp and everytime you click on a photo, open instagram to vote it.

I have some problems because of iframes, I cannot show instagram inside an iframe to keep it inside my webpage and have a button to go back. So I am trying to launch safari to open that link so I can vote the page and change app to mine again.

In android I don't have problems since I have back button on mobile phone, same in winpho.

I make a call to other page with instagram link, this is the code in javascript:

```
    <body id="responsiveDemo">  
    <div data-role="page" id="test" data-theme="g">
        <div data-theme="g" data-role="header">
            <a href="javascript:history.back()" data-icon="back" data-iconpos="notext"></a>
            <h1>Instagram</h1>
        </div>

        <div data-role="content">

        <iframe id="iframeInstagram" src="" name="IframeInstagram" style="width: 100%; height: 800px; border: medium none;visibility: visible;"></iframe>

      <!--  <img id="iframeInstagram" src="">-->

                    <script>
    $(document).on("pageshow", '#test', function() {
                    var query = location.search.substring(1);
                    //console.log(query);
                    var parameters = {};
                    var keyValues = query.split(/&/);
                    for (var i = 0; i < keyValues.length;i++) {
                        var keyValuePairs = keyValues[i].split(/==/);
                        var key = keyValuePairs[0];
                        var value = keyValuePairs[1];
                        parameters[key] = value;
                    }




                        var is_uiwebview = /(iPhone|iPod|iPad).*AppleWebKit(?!.*Safari)/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
                        var is_safari_or_uiwebview = /(iPhone|iPod|iPad).*AppleWebKit/i.test(navigator.userAgent);

                        if(is_safari_or_uiwebview){ //Es un ios
                            var a = document.createElement('a');
                            a.setAttribute("href", parameters['instagram']);
                            a.setAttribute("target", "_blank");

                            var dispatch = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
                            dispatch.initEvent("click", true, true);
                            a.dispatchEvent(dispatch);
                        }else{ //No es un ios
                            document.getElementById('iframeInstagram').src = parameters['instagram'] + 'embed';
                        }

                        });




                    </script>



        </div> <!-- /content -->
    </div>
    </body>
```

I just can try on ios simulator because I will not have a phone at least till this afternoon or tomorrow.

Can you tell me if this is the correct way of opening safari from webapp? In simulator, it makes all in the same app and not opens safari. I guess, IOS7 is the main target

I am reading about it and I am very confused. In some posts appear that in ios7 this works, in others that it depends on the update....